# intel MFSYS25 blade server- trunk port configuration

Tags: cisco, intel, blade-server, trunk

Can any one help me configure the Intel blade MFSYS25 switch module to communicate to Cisco devices through trunk? I tried for many hours, seems it doesn't work! There seems to be no documentation on this.

I just need to connect my Cisco switche's trunk ports to the virtual machines on blades.
Thanks